# Wide character and Locale

Tags: c, encoding, locale

#1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"C");
    wprintf(L"大\n");
    
    return 0;
}

//result : ?
```

#2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"C");
    printf("大\n");
    
    return 0;
}

//result : 大
```

The difference between #1 and #2 is just printing function.

I expect that if wide character doesnt printed in certain locale, then multibyte character also should not be printed in the same locale.

I'm curious why multibyte string is printed(#2), whereas wide character string doesnt printed(#1)?

I know if locale is not `"C"`, wide character will be printed well. but why?? What is the locale exactly do?

+) I thought multibyte characer encoding is locale dependent, but multibyte character is printed well regradless of locale.. How computer can determine multibyte character encoding?

Comment: note 1: `setlocale` is just a *local* thing (so just within program). It changes nothing on environment, so both programs will print something which may be incompatible with terminal locale. Note 2: contrary to Python, the `*printf` in C just write that strings in the output buffer, without changes (ignoring locale). Note 3: `wprintf` will print multibyte characters without further changes. Note 4: to test locales and characters you must write to a file, else you have strange interaction with terminal expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with `Windows Console` you should use `_setmode` function to change the default translation mode of `stdout` to Unicode, if you want to work with wide strings.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"C");
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"大\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170